# How can I get the ZeroFriction that the terrain is using?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In the Assets I have a ZeroFriction and I dragged that ZeroFriction to the Terrain > Collider > Material

[image: Zero Friction]

This is the ZeroFriction settings :

[image: ZeroFriction settings]

Than in a script I did :

```
private float SetTerrainDynamicFriction(float DynamicFriction)
    {
        return Terrain.activeTerrain.GetComponent<TerrainCollider>().material.dynamicFriction = DynamicFriction;
    }
```

And using it :

```
SetTerrainDynamicFriction(2);
```

I want to change the Dynamic Friction of the ZeroFriction to 2.

The problem I think is I'm trying to change it through the terrain and I need to change the value of the ZeroFriction directly in the Assets :

The path is : Assets > Standard Assets > PhysicsMaterials

[image: ZeroFriction direct path]

I'm not sure how to access the ZeroFriction directly in the path and change the Dynamic Friction ?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to add a PhysicMaterial variable at the top of the script :

```
public PhysicMaterial zeroFrictionMaterial;
```

Than in the method at the bottom :

```
private float SetTerrainDynamicFriction(float DynamicFriction)
    {
        return zeroFrictionMaterial.dynamicFriction = DynamicFriction;
    }
```

And using it :

```
SetTerrainDynamicFriction(2);
```

Still didn't solve my problem 100% because the player is still changing a bit his position on the terrain sliding a bit almost not notice and affecting but I wonder what values and properties you should change in the ZeroFriction to make the player not moving at all ? I thought changing the Dynamic Friction to 2 will do it but it's not not 100% yet.

Anyway for my question this is the solution.

Maybe the method name should be : SetZeroFrictiomDynamicFriction ? Because I'm changing it directly on the ZeroFriction not on the Terrain object. Anyway it's working.